# RavenDB Index on nested Dictionary property

Tags: ravendb

I'm not sure what's the problem but I must be doing something wrong as the index is empty, even if I remove the `where b.Status == ...` line.
Any ideas?

```
public class Bookings_ToBeScheduled : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Inspection, BookingRequest>
{
    public Bookings_ToBeScheduled()
    {
        Map = inspections =>
            from i in inspections
            from b in i.Bookings.Values
            where b.Status == BookingStatus.Requested || b.Status == BookingStatus.InspectorAssigned
            select new
            {
                InspectionId = i.Id,
                i.InspectionType,
                b.BookingNumber
            };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, instead:

```
public class Bookings_ToBeScheduled : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Inspection, BookingRequest>
{
    public Bookings_ToBeScheduled()
    {
        Map = inspections =>
            from i in inspections

            select new
            {
                InspectionId = i.Id,
                i.InspectionType,
/*
 BookingNumber = i.Bookings.Values
          .Where(b => b.Status == BookingStatus.Requested || b.Status == BookingStatus.InspectorAssigned)
          .Selcet(b=>  b.BookingNumber)

*/
                BookingNumber = from b in i.Bookings.Values
                                where b.Status == BookingStatus.Requested || b.Status == BookingStatus.InspectorAssigned
                                select b.BookingNumber
            };
    }
}
```

It is generally better not to have a fanout (multiple entries per document) in the index.
I'm not sure off the top of my head which version of BookingNumber will work, the Linq method one will certainly will.

Comment: Thanks Ayende, I found a solution. The problem was selecting from the Dictionary '.Values' so this worked for me - from b in i.Bookings then using b.Value.BookingNumber